# Another IE jQuery AJAX/post problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

OK so i have this website, http://www.leinstein.dk.

You will see "Hello World!" This is from ok.php, ive made a script that refreshes ok.php after 10 seconds. Anyways, This does not show in IE.
I dont know why, and i hope you can help me out.

Here's My script:

```
function ajax_update()
{
      cache: false
 /* var wrapperId  = '#wtf'; */
 var postFile = 'ok.php';
    $.post("ok.php", function(data){
 cache: false
          $("#wtf").html(data);
      });  
 setTimeout('ajax_update()', 10000);

}
```

And here's index.php:

```
<?
header("cache-control: no-cache");
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax_framework.js" language="javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<!-- AJAX UPDATE COMMENTS BEGIN -->
<body onload="ajax_update();">
<!-- AJAX UPDATE END -->
<br>

<div id="wtf"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in forward..!

Comment: You have obvious script errors (random `cache: false` lines)

Comment: Have you tried running something like Fiddler to peek at what those http requests look like?

Comment: Ive just used firebug to see http request.. and i got 304 Not Modified on on this:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: And for some reason i am getting (i am using FF firebug, Where the script works)
ok.php?_=1265410469407 (random numbers each 10 seconds) which i dont know why i get that.. :-S 
And besides that, i get 304 not modified on ajax_framework.js (Where the script is?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just put `cache: false` throughout your code in random spots.  Please [learn basic Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) syntax before starting to write code.  You'll probably learn much more by following a basic tutorial than posting a bunch of localized questions here on StackOverflow.

I will, however, show you what your function should look like *this time*.  But I strongly recommend reading the tutorial that I have provided a link to.

```
function ajax_update()  { 
  $.post("ok.php", function(data){ 
    $("#wtf").html(data); 
    setTimeout(ajax_update, 10000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for link. I tried this, but unfourtanly like the other its not working..

Comment: It's not working?  Awww, what a shame.  If only my ESP-level debugger wasn't full of bugs itself...

Comment: You probably have Javascript disabled LOL

Comment: It is likely a HTTP header issue with your handler (ok.php)

Comment: Right now this is what ok.php looks like:
<?php
ob_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
ob_flush();
?> 
Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

```
function ajax_update()
{
      var postFile = 'ok.php';

      $.post("ok.php", function(data){
          $("#wtf").html(data);
      });  

    setTimeout(ajax_update, 10000);
}
```

Youre also going to run into a situation where youre trying to modify the DOM before its ready because youre invoking this function at body.onLoad but the entire page needs to beready in order to use `$('#wtf')`. you need to rethink this... and probably brush up on js syntax :-)

Comment: Either way is valid.  That's not the problem.

Comment: Yeah i realized that after the fact... the random cache line and other things... edited to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap your function in a ready jQuery function, like that you wont need to wait the loading of all the page element, just the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```