# AJAX UPDATE + PHP + IE = Fail?

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer

Following from this thread: [Another IE jQuery AJAX/post problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209260/another-ie-jquery-ajax-post-problem) (please read the thread to understand this one)

Now i've got an solution for the thread above.. But, the `ok.php` (the site it updates each 10 seconds, with AJAX script) Doesn't show in IE if the response contain HTML code. With this I mean, if i have:
(ok.php)

```
<?php
ob_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ob_flush();
echo "hello";
?>
```

It will work in both IE and FF... However if i have:
(in ok.php)

> ```
> <?php
> ob_start();
> header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
> header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
> header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
> ob_flush();
> include "../tilslut.php";
> $sql = "SELECT id FROM member_comments WHERE fID = '19'";
>  $query = mysql_query($sql);
>  $number = mysql_num_rows($query);
>  echo("There is <b>".$number."</b> comments!<br><br>");
> ?>
> ```

It will work/show only in firefox, not in IE.

Help me out! :( Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does ../tilslut.php contain?  it looks like your response isn't really an HTML page (no html, head, body tags)

Comment: i guess it's alright because the html returned is then added into a div via jQuery. @scunliffe - see previous post.

Comment: tilslut.php is like a config.php connects to database.

Comment: This can probably be shortened to: Ajax + IE = Fail.

Comment: Why the ob_start();? Doesn't that require an ob_end_flush(); at the end of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the path try to use include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../tilslut.php'). This should throw you errors but its better to do it that way. Try to put the ajax_update in a script like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ajax_update();});
</script>
```

instead of the onload

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) addon for IE that will let you inspect your HTTP traffic.

With that you'll be able to verify that you are `sending` the correct request and `returning` the correct response.

Also verify using view-source or the IE developer tools that you aren't getting the content back ok, but somehow IE isn't showing it (e.g. it is in the source, but not visible)

For example if you were trying to set your returned HTML as the content of a Table or Select list... this would fail in IE.